# How to install Graphic Magick with GPU support (opencl)?

Tags: intel-graphics, imagemagick, opencl

Considering ImageMagick there is opencl enable option. If we enable it, then the ImageMagick or Magick++ or JMagick will run in GPU (Intel GPU) else they will run in CPU.

Similarly, is there any way to install GraphicMagick, such that it could run in GPU?

I have downloaded graphicsmagick-1.3.18

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

GraphicsMagick author is [against GPU using](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/FAQ.html#are-there-any-plans-to-use-opencl-or-cuda-to-use-a-gpu) in GraphicsMagick, so there is no support